# Managed C++ dll in C#: Can only reference parameterless constructors

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllexport

I'm trying to import a 3rd party dll linked as managed C++ into C# in VS2010. As far as I understand this should be possible. The dll also loads just fine through Add Reference, but I cannot access anything in the namespace even though the content of the entire DLL is visible in the Object Browser

There is an exception, though: If I make the classes public in the DLL (i have the source code), I can access the classes' parameterless constructors, but that's it. 
I've tried all sorts of solutions, including enclosing everything in `extern "C++"` but that doesn't do any bit of difference.

What could I be doing wrong? Note that the C++ project does not have a dllMAin file.

The classes are declared like this in the C++ project:

```
#ifndef _POINT_H
#define _POINT_H
***usings***
namespace NS {
    public class __declspec(dllexport) Point
    {
    private:
        double* pstart_;
        int n_;
    public :
        Point()
        : pstart_(0), n_(0)
        {}
         Point(double x, double y)
        : pstart_(new double[2]), n_(2)
        {
        pstart_[0] = x;
        pstart_[1] = y;
        }
    Methods etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: They are not managed classes, even though they were compiled with the C++/CLI compiler.  Which turns them into opaque value types in the assembly manifest, otherwise useless from C#.  A usable managed class needs to be declared as **ref class**.  Clearly the author didn't intend you to use these classes, although there's some evidence he didn't know what he was doing.

Comment: Crapness. Does this mean that P/Invoke is probably my only option?

Comment: Talk to the author of this code, small odds you will find him here.

Comment: Hans Passant's comment is correct.